# How can I toggle a hidden radio button with a link in jQuery 1.9?

Tags: jquery

I tried searching for this, but usually people want to toggle "divs" with a radio button, I however, would like to toggle a hidden radio button with a link.

I have a radio button group like this:

```
<label class="radio inline hidden"><input class="radio_buttons" id="orderDirectionASC" name="orderDirection" type="radio" value="1" /> ASC</label>

<label class="radio inline hidden"><input class="radio_buttons" id="orderDirectionDESC" name="orderDirection" type="radio" value="0" /> DESC</label>
```

So, just to make my form prettier instead of letting the user click on the radio buttons, I wanted to have an image of an up-arrow or down-arrow that toggles on click. Something like this:

```
<a href="##" class="directiontoggle">
<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
</a>
```

Of course only one of those would show up at a time, so when the radio button toggles, so do those images. So if the radio is set to 1, it shows the up arrow and vice versa.

Oh and also I should mention, that I set the radio button to up or down based on a URL variable on pageload in my ColdFusion code. I don't know if that helps or not...

Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I figured it out. It may not be the most elegant way to do this, but it works. Suggestions for improvement are welcome :)

1st on page load I either hide the arrow up or down, depending on what the initial selection is.

```
<cfif orderDirection eq 1>
    $('.directiontoggleDOWN').hide();
<cfelse>
    $('.directiontoggleUP').hide();
</cfif>
```

Then I have this jQuery code:

```
        $('.directiontoggleUP').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("##orderDirectionDESC").prop("checked", true); 
            $('.directiontoggleUP').hide();
            $('.directiontoggleDOWN').show();
        });
        $('.directiontoggleDOWN').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("##orderDirectionASC").prop("checked", true); 
            $('.directiontoggleDOWN').hide();
            $('.directiontoggleUP').show();
        });
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
                <a href="##" class="directiontoggleUP">   
                    <i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="##" class="directiontoggleDOWN">
                    <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
                </a>
```

So yea, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.directiontoggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var radio  = $('#orderDirectionASC'), //radio button to toggle
        _check = radio.is(':checked');    //is it checked ?

    $('i', this).toggle(); // toggle both i elements, one should be hidden by CSS

    radio.prop('checked', !_check); // toggle radio button
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If DESC is selected on page load, and I click the toggle, it switches it to ASC and just removes the arrows completely. And if ASC is selected on page load, clicking the toggle just removes the arrow, but does not select the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe example like this will be good for you. It works using pure HTML + CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/t6kBQ/5/

Html is following

```
<div id="sites">
    <input type="radio" name="arrows" id="so" value="stackoverflow" /><label for="so"><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" alt="Stack Overflow" />ASC</label>
    <br/>
     <input type="radio" name="arrows" id="sf" value="serverfault" /><label for="sf"><img src="http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/favicon.ico" alt="Server Fault" />DESC</label>
</div>
```

CSS is following:

```
.input_hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#sites label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}


#sites label:hover {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#sites label img {
    padding: 3px;

}
```

p.s. Sorry for stupid icons :)